# Can there be a non-polynomial continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has multiple zero-valued points?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

1) Is there any non-polynomial function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has more than one zero-valued point in domain?

2) Is there any non-polynomial function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has countable infinite number of zero-valued points?

Non-polynomial functions can have polynomial terms - but function must contain non-polynomial terms.

OOps. Excluding ones that can be expressed by Taylor series using $x=c$ where $c$ is some constant.

Answer (score 7):

Sure: $f(x)=\sin x$, unless I’m completely misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Jeremy: You and Ittay can fight over the cosine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For example a [surjective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function): $f(x)=x \sin x$.

You can construct a non-polynomial function with some fixed (finite) set of zeros by taking an appropriate polynomial and wrap it into [$\arctan$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions). For example [$\arctan \left((x-1)(x-2)\right)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arctan%28%28x-1%29%28x-2%29%29) is  a non-polynomial function with zeroes at 1 and 2.